# How do I solve $\int s 7^{s} ds$ with integration by parts?

Tags: integration

I do not know if I should use exponential laws or logarithms first... I am completely lost! Please help!

$\int s 7^{s} ds$

Thanks in advance

Comment: And if you have only two possibilities, why don't you try both and see yourself what happens? It's the way to learn.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Just a classical trick : $a^x=e^{x \log(a)}$. So $$\int s 7^{s} ds=\int s e^{s \log(7)} ds$$ from which it becomes obvious that integration by parts will lead to the desired result.

I am sure that you can take from here.

Comment: I get 7(s/2)(e^s). Am I correct? Also, I plugged in the value in the value in wolfram alpha and it did not give me that. Therefore, I must be wrong in my result right? Would it be possible to help me any further?

Comment: @user4681. This is wrong. To make your life easier, change variable $x=s \log(7)$. You should arrive to a very simple integrand from which the remaining will easily follow. To check the validity of your answer, compute its derivative wrt $s$; do you obtain your integrand ?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** The rule for integration by parts is $$ \int u\, dv =uv -\int v\, du.$$ You have to pick which of $s$ and $7^s$ is $u$ and which is $dv$. There are only two possibilities. One will raise the power of $s$ (not helpful), and the other will lower it (very helpful). Can you take it from here? Just begin writing out the two possibilities in parallel and see how they develop together.

Comment: Hmm.. so if I choose s as my u it will disappear since du = 1? and dv = 7^2.. I dont really get it. Could you help me anyfurther? many thanks!

Comment: If $u=7^s$ and $dv=s\,ds$, then $du=(7^s\log 7)ds$ and $v=s^2/2$, not very helpful for integration by parts (write out what it gives you). But if you choose $u=s$ and $dv = 7^s\,ds$, then $du=ds$ and $v = 7^s/\log 7$, much more helpful for integration by parts (again, write you what it gives you -- there will be another integral to evaluate, but it is easier than the original). Helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Using integration by parts, as well as the following identity:

$ ∫ a^xdx = \left(a^x\right)/\log \left(a\right)$

{ We receive this identity by the following trick:

$ a^x = \exp \left(\log \left(a^x\right)\right) = \exp \left(x\log \left(a\right)\right) $ , as such, the integral is: $∫ a^xdx = ∫ \exp \left(x\log \left(a\right)\right) = 1/\log \left(a\right) * \exp \left(x\log \left(a\right)\right) = a^x / \log \left(a\right) $ }

you can define:

$u := s$ and $v' := 7^s$

As such, the result of your integral will be:

$ = uv - ∫ u'v 
= s\left(7^s / \log \left(7\right)\right) - ∫ \left(7^s / \log \left(7\right)\right)ds 
= s\left(7^s / \log \left(7\right)\right) - 1/\log \left(7\right)∫ 7^sds = s\left(7^s / \log \left(7\right)\right) - 1/\log \left(7\right)\left(\left(7^s / \log \left(7\right)\right)\right)$

Doing some transformations, you will receive:

$ = \left(7^s\left(s*\log \left(7\right) - 1\right)\right) / \log ^2\left(7\right) + C $ as the exact solution.

Comment: Your answer does make sense and it was the answer I got from Wolfram Alpha. The only part I do not get is that when you integrate 7^s you get 7^s/log(7). Could you please explain why? Thank you so much!

Comment: You can say that:  $ a^x = e^(log(a^x)) = e^(xlog(a))$

Integrating this gives you the following result:

$\int a^xdx = \int e^(xlog(a)) = 1/log(a) * e^xlog(a) = a^x/log(a)$

Comment: Could you walk me to the process? I get it until you integrate e^(xlog(a)).. I am confused because I learned that the integral of e^x is just e^x... I dont get where you get the 1/log(a). Also, do you get e^x(log(a)) because you can split e^(xlog(a)) into (e^x)(e^log(a)) and the latter cancels out? Im confused. Thank you very much for your patience and help!

Comment: Please excuse for the horrific editing above. I just edited my answer to give an explanation...

Comment: I did it without any rule:

When you derive $exp(ax)$ you get $a*exp(ax)$

So if you want to integrate $exp(ax)$ you have to search for an expression that gives you $exp(ax)$ when derived, which happens to be $1/a * exp(ax)$.

Is it clearer now?

Answer (score 0):

Or you can proceed by trial differentiation. So take $f(x)=x\cdot 7^x$ and compute
$$
f'(x)=7^x(x+\ln(7))=f(x)+7^x\ln(7)
$$
From that you can guess the form of the anti-derivative.